# Is "const int x = get();" legal in C?Can we assign a function's return value to a constant at declaration?

Tags: c, constants

A highly reputed contributor `"R.."` on this forum explicitly told me this 2 days back:

`Initializers for objects of static storage duration must be constant expressions. The result of a function call is not a constant expression.`

He was talking about global variables.But I am not sure what goes with constants declared inside the `main()` function, or any function for that matter.Though intuitively I feel it is so even for constants declared within functions,the following program sourced from the following link, with its supposedly `correct` answer, is confusing me.

http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/const/discussion-546

```
#include<stdio.h>
int get();

int main()
{
    const int x = get();
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}

int get()
{
    return 20;
}
```

So can anyone explain whether it's valid in C to assign a return value to a constant?

Comment: ... and IIRC, I told you two days ago that there's no such thing as *global variables* in C, and that you're referring to variables declared at file scope which have static storage duration. There's a pretty large difference. Variables declared at file scope have much less visibility; They're *only* visible in their own translation unit, *after* their declaration. Global variables are also visible outside of their translation unit, and prior to their declaration.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour In what context you posted this comment?Are you `R..` using another ID?Who is IIRC? BTW, are there really no global variables in C? Aren't variables declared outside all functions global variables?

Comment: In the context of "global variables in C", which don't exist for the reasons I indicated above, I mentioned that they don't exist. I'm not R.. IIRC stands for "If I recall correctly". You can search for "global" in the C standard, if you like, and it'll come up with nothing relevant. As I said previously, variables declared outside all functions are declared *at file scope*, with *static storage duration* and they're visible *only from the point of declaration up until the end of the translation unit*. This is different to the definition of *global variable* in other languages.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I had drilled it into my head as a hard N fast rule that variables outside functions are called "Global Variables"in C.Can you give a rigorous definition?What do I call such variables in C then?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Even some books and popular websites on C use that term.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) seems to give a pretty good definition, in the very first sentence. What is it you don't understand about "file scope"? Is `int foo = bar; int bar = 0;` correct? Why not? Doesn't that mean "bar isn't accessible in every scope"? Wouldn't that be a violation of the definition of "global"?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Ah!Now that makes things a lot clearer.`int foo=bar; int bar=0;` isn't correct because the first statement won't recognize `bar`,but then `bar` is supposed to be  accessible everywhere around the file.So it's not certainly `global`.Now did I understand the whole thing?Please say yes or no.

Comment: Yes. Consider in Javascript, where `function foo() { bar = 42; }` `var bar = 0;` is valid... Consider that, in C#, one module might be compiled and the compiled `dll` linked to an `exe`. Any globals in that `dll` are visible to the `exe`. Is this true of variables declared at file scope in C?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Glad that I understood.As of `dll` and `exe`,I am not very knowledgeable about that.All I know is that in multi-file C source code, if a variable is defined in `file1` but also is used in `file2`,then in `file2` it is declared with the `extern` keyword.

Comment: I'm glad you're now aware, if only partially, of the distinction between *global variables* and *variables declared at file scope*. This'll help you understand *global variables* better in other programming languages.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour partially?Even after so much discussion?What am I yet to learn then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly valid, since your variable is automatic, i.e. *not* `static`.

The restrictions apply to `static` variables, whose values must be known at compile-time.

Note that C differentiates between "constant expressions" and other expressions, and that the initializer value used for `static` variables must be such a constant expression. For non-`static` variables, there is no such requirement.

Comment: It will be very much helpful if you can share further facts about this.Please elaborate a little unless this question is a duplicate.I am sure many other newbies would love to learn more about it.

Comment: In a language with as much undefined and implementation-defined behaviour as C, "just try it" is almost never a useful response to a question of "is this legal?".

Comment: @Cairnarvon Great, as if I wasn't confused already, now I see someone with 123k reputation being downvoted.`Cairnarvon` please post it in an answer, I am sure many others like me will benefit.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Fair point, although the suggestion "try it" is pretty common around here it does leave a bit too much to the implementation. I re-wrote, thanks.

Comment: @SheerFish Downvoting me is fine, it makes me better! Rep is nice but not magical.

Comment: @unwind `unwind` please elaborate your answer a little more.It seems like there is too much to this issue.

Comment: @unwind Unwind,help me out on this.A user called `undefined behavior` is telling me that there are no global variables in C and that "global variables in C" is a  misleading term.Please confirm this.I had it drilled into my head that in C all variables at file scope,declared outside all functions are called `global variables`

Comment: @Koushik Some may feel you are stalking `unwind` on this forum, but I would say your comment reminds me of the story about Mathematicians Hardy & Ramanujam when they were travelling in a car and saw the registration-plate of a passing cab.Not saying you are the next Ramanujam though :-)

Comment: mot that i stalk but i really appreciate the quality of the questions and answers here. your questions are also tricky .thanks for the opportunity to learn:-). of course i'm not ramanujan and i cannot even dream to be:-)

Comment: @Koushik I checked, it would be another +20.It's 123436 now

Comment: no actually his reputation wont get updated coz its reached its limit or so i guess..it should have been complete by now.:-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this assignment is valid C. But `x` is not a constant expression, it is a const-qualified variable, which is not the same thing (in C at least).

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.6 Constant expressions**
>
> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands
>   that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof`
>   expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating
>    constants that are the immediate operands of casts.

Integer constants look like `42`, `0L` or `89.0`. For example, in the following code snippet, `2` is an integer constant, but `x` is not.

```
const int x = 2;
```

Comment: It will be immensely helpful if you elaborate a little about the difference between const-qualified variables and constant expressions in this context.Thanks

Comment: Though I must admit your `avatar-photo` distracted me for a while.We don't see that much on this forum, and very little next to such high reputation

Comment: Come on Mademoiselle from France,please elaborate a little more about `const-qualified variable` vs `const-qualified variable` in this regard.Plz

Comment: @SheerFish Hasn't anyone ever warned you about trap representations on the internet?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour What's `trap representations`?Please tell

Comment: @SheerFish "trap representations" is for e.g like a union having int and double, you assign a value to double but access it through int variable(which is undefined). you "maybe"(due to implementation) able modify the value of a const variable but its undefined

Comment: @SheerFish That's not a photo of the user Kirilenko, it's [the Tennis player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Kirilenko), of whom our Kirilenko apparently is a fan.

Comment: @DanielFischer Didn't know that.Stopped watching Tennis since the days of Sharapova.Russian players are more famous off the court than they are on it.

Answer (score 2):

What I think makes you confused is that you are mixing up the *type qualifier* `const`, with the *storage class specifier* `static`. These are entirely different features, you can't compare them with each other.

`const` means that a variable is read-only within the scope where it was declared, and it can only be given a value when it is initialized. That is, on the same line where the `const` variable was defined. It means nothing else.

*Static storage duration* means that a variable will exist throughout the whole execution of a program. All variables that are declared as `static` and all variables that declared at file scope ("globals") have static storage duration. As mentioned, variables with static storage duration can only be initialized with a *constant expression*, which is not to be confused with read-only variables declared as `const`.

> So can anyone explain whether it's valid in C to assign a return value to a constant?

It depends.

- Any variable declared at file scope has static storage duration.
- A variable with static storage duration must be initialized with a constant expression.
- A return value from a function is not a constant expression.
- Thus a variable with static storage duration cannot be initialized with a return value from a function.

As you can see, that had nothing to do with the `const` keyword but everything to do with where the variable was declared. Had the variable, `const` or not, been declared inside a local scope, it would be perfectly fine to initialize it with any value, as illustrated by your code example.